# Erro definir getElementById?

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho um elemento onde o atributo `id` é um inteiro. Estou tentando definir, mas não estou conseguindo.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
var 1 = document.getElementById(1).value
```

***Esta correto?***

Comment: Não, está você não pode definir um número para variavel em qualquer linguagem e no `getElementById("1").value` é um texto dentro do paramentro. Tem como você colocar a tag?

Answer (score 8):

Os problemas são:

1. Variáveis **não podem** ser compostas apenas de numeros `var 1; var 2;`
2. O parâmetro no `getElementById` deve ser `string`

**Extras:**

- [HTML4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id): O atributo ID nunca pode se repetir e deve começar com letras e não deve conter espaços
- [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): É mais permissivo, todavia ainda sim não aceita espaços.
- IDs nunca devem se repetir em uma mesma página HTML

### O problema é por onde começar a aprender

O problema da pergunta não é o seu erro, mas é um problema comum de quem está começando a aprender, pois costumam inventar da *própria cabeça* ou sair *usando aleatoriamente uma função ou código*. Para todas tecnologias populares sempre existe uma documentação ao menos (oficial ou não oficial), o mesmo vale para JavaScript que é usada amplamente, então não tente usar sem seguir ao menos um exemplo que esteja na documentação, se tiver dificuldades leia os detalhes da própria documentação sobre a função que esta tentando usar no momento, então aprenda o básico primeiro, pois não adianta pular etapas.

Em JavaScript comece por algo como: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript

Para aprender a usar e declarar variáveis leia na DOC:

- [Declarando variáveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Declarando_vari%C3%A1veis)

Para aprender sobre o uso do `getElementById`:

- [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Outros links dentro da doc úteis para começar:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numeros_e_datas
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Formatando_texto
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators
- [https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Funções](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es)
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Lacos_e_iteracoes

> A maior parte das "docs" de javascript tem algum problema, principalmente em português, mas ainda sim para aprender o básico o link da Mozilla atende bem

### Para resolver

Para resolver pode fazer algo como:

```
document.getElementById("item_1").value;
```

E mudar o HTML para algo como (apesar do HTML5 ser mais permissivo quanto ao `ID`):

Claro que pode usar números no ID sendo HTML5, como já disse, mas no caso não sei quais os navegadores que pretende rodar e mesmo que funcione no HTML4, ainda você pdoe se atrapalhar.

Um exemplo:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var item1 = document.getElementById("item_1");
    var button = document.getElementById("enviar");
  
    button.onclick = function() {
        console.log(item1.value);
    };
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Olá mundo" id="item_1">

<button id="enviar">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que o nome da tua variável é um inteiro, nunca deves fazer isso, até porque se desse (ainda bem que não dá) iria trazer imensos problemas, assim como o id deve ser passado como string dentro do metodo `getElementById()`, faz o seguinte:

```js
var val_1 = document.getElementById("1").value;
alert(val_1);
```

```html
<input id="1" value="heya">
```

E assim como é mencionado na resposta do Virgilio, também deves evitar usar somente um número como id, nem deves colocar o número no inicio do nome do `id`, porque se quiseres estilizar (CSS) usando o `id` como selector não vais conseguir, ex:

```css
#1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="1" value="heya">
```

Exemplo que funciona:

```css
#a1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="a1" value="heya">
```

Answer (score 5):

O teu problema está no nome da variável. Variáveis com numeros no inicio do nome são inválidas.

- `div1` funciona como nome de variável
- `1div` ou `1` não funciona como nome de variável

O erro que isso dá diz isso, "apareceu um numero inesperado":

> (index):45 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

O [.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) aceita uma variável ou *string* como argumento. Podes usar um numero, que é aceite em HTML5, mas o correto é usar uma string.

Exemplo:

```js
var um = document.getElementById(1);
um.style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Não é uma boa prática colocar a `id` ([leia](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)) de qualquer `tag` [html](/questions/tagged/html) somente com um número coloque sempre a inicial uma letra (*exemplo:* **`a1`**, **`b1`**, etc.), no código tem o problema de colocar um número como variável (*isso não pode em qualquer linguagem, segue um padrão um letra e depois pode ter números*, logo abaixo tem a explicação de criação de variaveis com [php](/questions/tagged/php) e [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)) e por fim o paramento dentro do [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp) é um texto (`getElementById("t1")`);

Para funcionar basicamente sem muitas mudanças:

```js
var numero = document.getElementById("1").value;
console.log(numero);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="100" id="1" name="t1" />
```

Uma maneira correta: O `id` foi adicionado um letra **t** e após um número `(t1)`:

```js
var numero = document.getElementById("t1").value;
console.log(numero);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="100" id="t1" name="t1" />
```

**Como definir uma variável?**

#### Javascript

*A linguagem JavaScript faz distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas.  Isso significa que um nome de variável, como myCounter, é diferente do nome de variável MYCounter.  Nomes de variáveis podem ser de qualquer comprimento.  As regras para a criação de nomes de variável legais são as seguintes:*

- *O primeiro caractere deve ser uma letra ASCII (em maiúscula ou minúscula) ou um caractere de sublinhado (_).  Observe que um número não pode ser usado como o primeiro caractere.*
- *Os caracteres subsequentes devem ser letras, números ou sublinhados (_).*
- *O nome da variável não deve ser uma [palavra reservada](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/0779sbks(v=vs.94).aspx).*

[Referencia e Direitos autorais - MSDN Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/67defydd(v=vs.94).aspx)

#### PHP

*Nomes de variável seguem as mesmas regras como outros rótulos no PHP. Um nome de variável válido inicia-se com uma letra ou sublinhado, seguido de qualquer número de letras, números ou sublinhados. Em uma expressão regular, poderia ser representado assim: `[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]**`*

[Referencia e direitos autoriais - Site PHP](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.basics.php).

<sub>Mesmo sendo uma definição para `PHP` segue a nomenclatura básica para criação de nomes de variáveis em programação.</sub>

Esses dois textos que explicam como criar nomes para variáveis vai permitir a compreensão melhor de como definir nomes inclusive de elementos de [html](/questions/tagged/html), porque, também são nomes de variáveis de tela, cuidado com repetição de nomes que pode ser um grande transtorno no desenvolvimento e use essas nomenclaturas que defini a criação de nomes de variaveis.

***Referencias:***

- [Variável (programação)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vari%C3%A1vel_(programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))
- [HTML DOM getElementById() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementbyid.asp)
- [HTML DOM id Property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp)
- [www.w3.org - 6 Basic HTML data types](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)